# How to implement Update Mechanism in MySql?

Tags: mysql, database

My Use Case :
I am trying to create a GUI and implement it with MYSQL Database. The problem I am facing is the scenario when I have to update a certain entry in the Database.

I know that we can update an Entry in MYSQL database using :

`ALTER TABLE <TABLENAME> SET <PARAMETERS=NEW VALUES> WHERE <CONDITION> ;`

For eg : If I want to change the name of the guy who id is 2 , I have to write :

`ALTER TABLE StudentInfo SET Name='ABC' WHERE id=2 ;`

But the problem is , in a GUI based environment , a user can choose to update any particular value wihtout having a constant condition like `id` in the previous example.

[image: pic1]

In the UI , the user can opt to select anything from the parameters and modify it and then click the update button.

Now How will I figure out what `<CONDITION>` to put in the MYSQL query when I need to update the database ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you update a by using the [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) command **not** [ALTER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html), which will change table. Your gui already knows ho tow identify the row in your case for example by the column name

```
UPDATE StudentInfo SET Name='ABC' WHERE Name='QUERTY';
```

SEE example

> ```
> CREATE TABLE StudentInfo(
>
>     Name VARCHAR(20),
>     class int,
>     section VARCHAR(2),
>     roll_no int
> );
> INSERT INTO StudentInfo VALUES ('abc',12,'A',18), ('xyz',12,'A',17),('QUERTY',12,'A',16)
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE  StudentInfo SET Name='ABC',class = 15,section = 'B',roll_no= 99 WHERE Name='QUERTY';
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM StudentInfo
> ```
>
> ```
> Name | class | section | roll_no
> :--- | ----: | :------ | ------:
> abc  |    12 | A       |      18
> xyz  |    12 | A       |      17
> ABC  |    15 | B       |      99
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8b414366aece08e4da3dd53d2f4560e5)*

The main problem is to identify the correct row, so you should have a field that is unique.

Like an id auto_increment, that is invisible for the user, but you can identify every row and use this id to update the row.

```
 UPDATE StudentInfo SET Name='ABC' WHERE id = 3;
```

So that if you have two rows with John Smith you still could update the right one

Comment: I don't think that will work since the user can opt to modify only `name` (in that case , we only have to `SET Name=....`) or can choose to modify 3 parameters. Best way imo would be to Delete  the previous entry and add the new one :-)

Comment: i impleneted such tables, so it is no problem even when name is primary key, you can change it, but you need foreign keys that update the name automatically. You can change in one swoop all fileds(columns) as long as mysql can find the row(or rows), the only think is to keep the constraints in mind